# Application without GUI blocks current screen after start

Tags: android, android-service

I created application without GUI, that has one Activity to Launch it.

The problem is, that after application started, the current screen become unactive, like the new Activity has been started.

The picture is the same, but not active.
It become active only after touch "back" or "home" button.

Activity code:

```
public class LaunchActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, MainService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.execdroid.LaunchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.execdroid.MainService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label= "@string/service_name">
    </service>

</application>
```

What should I change for save current screen active after application starts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to finish your activity after starting a service. Try adding `finish()` after `startService(serviceIntent);`

Tested this just now - works correctly.